Geocoding - Japanese address start to timeout without url encoding from 12th Oct 2024
Here is example of call from Golang without url encoding.
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=大田区北千束３丁目&key=xxxx(please change to key)

Above was returning result until 11th oct 2024 but on 12th oct 2024 the same request would timeout after long wait.
Does any body know any changes done in API or has similar experience?
